# running a job in foreach loop with dynamic parameters spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, jobs

I have created a spring batch job with spring boot.
I customized the Reader to get json data from REST API and convert data to java object and the Writer will push data to queue.
i am calling my job in foreach loop to set parameters and send request to REST API with different langauges.
for the first iteration my job runs successfully but for other iteration it just display that it has finished.

Batch configuration :

```
@Configuration
   @EnableBatchProcessing
   public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory; 
         
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public RestWebClient webClient;
    
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Code> reader() {
        return new CodeAndLabelRestItemReader(webClient);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CodeAndLabelItemProcessor processor() {
        return new CodeAndLabelItemProcessor("France","DP","transaction");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<CodeAndLabel> calWriter(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        
        return new CodeAndLabelItemWriter(amqpTemplate);             
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "importJob")
    public Job importCodesAndLabelsJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step stepJms) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(stepJms)
                .end()
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step stepJms(ItemWriter<CodeAndLabel> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepJms")
                .<Code, CodeAndLabel>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
```

Reader :

```
public class CodeAndLabelRestItemReader implements ItemReader<Code>{

private final RestWebClient webClient;

private int nextCodeIndex;
private List<Code> codes;


public CodeAndLabelRestItemReader(RestWebClient webClient) {
    this.webClient = webClient;     
    nextCodeIndex = 0;
}

@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
    JobParameters jobParameters = stepExecution.getJobParameters();
    this.webClient.setEndPointSuffix(jobParameters.getString("endPointSuffix"));
}

@Override
public Code read()  {
    if(codesAndLabelsListNotInitialized()) {
        codes = webClient.getCodes();
    }
    
    Code nextCode = null;
    
    if (nextCodeIndex < codes.size()) {
        nextCode = codes.get(nextCodeIndex);
        nextCodeIndex++;
    }

    return nextCode;
}

private boolean codesAndLabelsListNotInitialized() {
    return this.codes == null;
}
```

}

Processor :

```
public class CodeAndLabelItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Code, CodeAndLabel> {

private String populationId;
private String populationDataProvider;
private String transactionId;

public CodeAndLabelItemProcessor(String populationId, String populationDataProvider, String transactionId) {
    this.populationId = populationId;
    this.populationDataProvider = populationDataProvider;
    this.transactionId = transactionId; 
}

@Override
public CodeAndLabel process(Code code) throws Exception {

    CodeAndLabel codeAndLabel = new CodeAndLabel();
    
    codeAndLabel.setUid(code.getUid());
    
    
    System.out.println("Converting (" + code + ") into (" + codeAndLabel + ")");
    
    return codeAndLabel;
}
```

}

Writer :

```
public class CodeAndLabelItemWriter implements ItemWriter<CodeAndLabel>{

private AmqpTemplate template;

public CodeAndLabelItemWriter(AmqpTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

@Override
public void write(List<? extends CodeAndLabel> items) throws Exception {
    
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        
        log.debug("Writing to RabbitMQ with " + items.size() + " items."); }
      
    for(CodeAndLabel item : items) {
        template.convertAndSend(BatchConfiguration.topicExchangeName,"com.batchprocessing.queue",item);
        System.out.println("item : "+item);
    }
    
}
```

}
Listener :

```
@Component
 public class JobCompletionNotificationListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
        System.out.println("JOB FINISHED");

    }
}
```

}

And the class running the job :

```
 @Component
 public class Initialization {
 // some code here
   String[] languages = processLanguage.split(";");             
                for(String language : languages) {

                    JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder() 
                              .addString("JobID",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))                        
                              .addString("endPointSuffix", 
     "/codeAndLabel".concat(language.toUpperCase()))
                              .toJobParameters();
                      jobLauncher.run(job, params);
                    
                }
```

Output :
for first iteration :

```
 Converting (WFR.SP.2C) into (WFR.SP.2C)
Converting (WFR.SP.3E) into (WFR.SP.3E)
Converting (WFR.SP.FC) into (WFR.SP.FC)
Converting (WFR.SP.FD) into (WFR.SP.FD)
Converting (WFR.SP.FI) into (WFR.SP.FI)
Converting (WFR.SP.FM) into (WFR.SP.FM)
item : WFR.SP.2C
item : WFR.SP.3E
item : WFR.SP.FC 
item : WFR.SP.FD
item : WFR.SP.FI
item : WFR.SP.FM
JOB FINISHED
```

for second iteration

```
JOB FINISHED
```

I think in the second iteration the job is not running Reader processor and writer beans i don't know why.
Can anyone give some help on this please?

Comment: You have a single instance of your reader etc. make them step scoped. At least the reader should be step scoped. Another thing is you probably are better of implementing `ItemStreamReader` instead of `ItemReader`. In the `open` method read the result van the endpoint and clean it in the `close` method instead of doing a check in the `read` method.